# ensure a dom environment is loaded for enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

I'm getting the following error when using Enzyme's `mount` function while testing a React app in Jest from the command line. It says that a DOM environment is not loaded, which I would think means I need to set up JSDOM. However, it appears that [JSDOM ships with Jest and is preconfigured](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string) according to Facebook's docs for Jest. Here's my test:

```
import React from 'react'
import MyComponent from '../src/components/MyComponent'
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { Menu, Dropdown, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

test('it works', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        <MyComponent />
    )
    expect(wrapper.contains('foobar')).toEqual(true)
});
```

And here's the error:

```
Enzyme's mount expects a DOM environment to be loaded, but found none

  at assertDomAvailable (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/build/Utils.js:107:11)
  at ReactSixteenAdapter.createMountRenderer (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:203:52)
  at ReactSixteenAdapter.createRenderer (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:384:25)
  at new ReactWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:96:54)
  at mount (node_modules/enzyme/build/mount.js:19:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/LinesheetModal.test.js:12:37)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

It appears to be related to enzyme-adapter-react-16. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: How are you running your tests ?

Comment: `npm test` on the command line, which is a command defined in package.json to run `jest` with no options

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the problem was that JSDOM and Enzyme were not set up correctly. Adding this file as a preloaded file to Jest fixed it:

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import jsdom from 'jsdom'

function setUpDomEnvironment() {
    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
    const dom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>', {url: 'http://localhost/'});
    const { window } = dom;

    global.window = window;
    global.document = window.document;
    global.navigator = {
        userAgent: 'node.js',
    };
    copyProps(window, global);
}

function copyProps(src, target) {
    const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(src)
        .filter(prop => typeof target[prop] === 'undefined')
        .map(prop => Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(src, prop));
    Object.defineProperties(target, props);
}

setUpDomEnvironment();

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

Answer (score 6):

Jest comes configured with JSDom out of the box, you need to make sure to use `testEnvironment: jsdom` in your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your jest config:

```
{
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  verbose: true,
  testURL: 'http://localhost/',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: another time I hit this - I used the async keyword on the describe() function

As I mentioned at https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1558, when I ran into this problem, it was due to passing and executing `done()` earlier than I should have.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed the following import in my test:

`import 'node_modules/jsdom-global/register'`